# How to prevent validation error on child/slave gridview from halting the application

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have master-slave `DataGrid`s, and the master contains different customer objects. When a specific customer is selected in the master, then the child shows the orders by that customers. (Each customer has an `ObservableCollection<order>` orders property. Orders have a delivery adress and a quantity. I use the following XML

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource Customers1}" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding /orders}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Delivery Adress">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <Binding Path="deliveryAddress"></Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <Binding Path="quantity">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
           <local:PositiveDoubleValidationRule></local:PositiveDoubleValidationRule>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Delivery dates and quantities are editable. I added a custom validation rule, that assures that quantity parses to a positive double, and otherwise causes a validation error. [image]

This works, but when I select another customer (Robert) while there is still a validation error in the orders of the current customer (Mark), and then select the customer that has the erroneous input again (Mark), the application stops working. (popup stating: [application name] has stopped working).

The error also occurs in other scenarios when the master is a `ComboBox`. However, strangely enough, it does not occur when the child is a simple `TextBox`.

Anyways, I have tried to come up with solutions that fix this, but so far I failed to come up with something decent. What would be good options?

EDIT: My class orders is implemented as follows:

```
class Order
{

    public string deliveryAddress
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double quantity
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Order()
    {

    }
}
```

Customers is an `ObservableCollection<customer>`, and each customer contains a property orders of type 
`ObservableCollection<Order>`.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this, but it seems to work in my example. When switching back to the customer with the validation error, the illegal input has been replaced with the original value.

Comment: @PeterHansen That is strange. What version of .net/WPF are you using? And how is your orders object implemented?

Comment: I have tried running the app on a computer with only .NET 4 installed and can see it crashing. The exception message is _'Defer Refresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or Edit Item transaction._ It happens because the DataGrid is stuck in editmode when it has validation errors and tries to refresh when coming back into view, which results in an exception. This bug has been fixed in .NET 4.5. You can google the error message, but there seems to be no perfect workaround. Maybe you can prompt the user to fix the validation errors before moving away from the DataGrid or something?

Answer (score 0):

Slim chances that it will help, but instead of using collection synchronization, try binding to selected item directly. Something like:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource Customers1}" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <DataGrid x:Name="MasterGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.orders, ElementName=MasterGrid}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Delivery Adress">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <Binding Path="deliveryAddress"></Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <Binding Path="quantity">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                           <local:PositiveDoubleValidationRule></local:PositiveDoubleValidationRule>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

It's better to have a property for the selected item on your view model than to bind with element name, but it's OK for testing.